# How to use npm packages with ASP.NET CORE 2 in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, npm, asp.net-core-mvc

I added some npm packages to my ASP.NET Core 2 project in Visual Studio 2017. Now I want to use css and js files from these packages, but VS doesn't see them because node_modules folder is outside wwwroot. What is the common practice here, how to make Visual Studio working with node_modules?

[image: IntelliSense errors - node_modules not found]

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you add the desired **npm packages** to your project, either through:

- `npm install` command

  or
- typing the package name and its version in the `npm configuration file`

  or
- searching the package in the `Library Dialog`, indicated in the following image for instance,
  [image]

they will be downloaded and restored in the node_modules folder. But to use them in your views, you need to add them to a client-side folder, such as `lib` under `wwwroot` folder.

You can copy them to `wwwroot` folder manually through the file system, or use the Library dialog:

1. right click on the lib directory inside wwwroot
2. Click Add, and choose Client-Side Library
3. From the provider, choose fileSystem (if desired files already exist in node_modules folder)
4. Choose all or specific files needed
5. Click install

However, you can manage this file copying operation manually.

Now, from the folders under `wwwroot`, you can drag and drop the file into your views. Be careful to omit **`~`** if your view is a `Layout`.

Hope this helped....
More details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: This is most simple answer that I have seen, especially if you don't want to use a crazy bundler.

Answer (score 2):

The common practice is to bundle your web assets, and put only the compiled bundle into your `wwwroot` folder.

Since Visual Studio 2015 we have multiple Taskrunners from the NPM World:

- Gulp
- Grunt

With them you could write a script, which automatically bundles your web assets. This script has full access to the NPM infrastructure.

There are some tools out there which make this super easy:

- gulp-uglify
- gulp-cssmin

More Information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-gulp

---

That said, it is also [possible to include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?tabs=aspnetcore2x) your npm folder:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "node_modules")),
        RequestPath = "/node_modules"
    });
}
```

But this would be the wrong way.

Comment: But that way, in order to use in Visual Studio these css/js files from node packages, first I will need to run this bundle script from command line right?

Comment: Not necessary. We have multiple options. Command Line, Task Runner Explorer, we can even bind it to the project build event (Which is only a good Idea if you regulary change your client side scripts, since it takes time). See the link, there is an example about using the Task Runner Explorer @Signum

Comment: A compiled bundle goes against using CDNs though. I would only bundle custom scripts and use CDNs for common libraries. That way they are cached already 90% of the time.