# How to instal jquery in .net core projet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

In VS2019 I created a .net core 3.0 project and  from Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Manage NuGet Package.... installed jQuery 3.4.1 on my project.

Search and install it successfully but it doesn't copy any file on my lib or on my solution just added bellow line on .csproj file.

```
<PackageReference Include="jQuery" Version="3.4.1" />
```

How can I handle it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Razor Core installing jquery.unobtrusive.ajax missing js files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57012147/razor-core-installing-jquery-unobtrusive-ajax-missing-js-files)

Comment: Please read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58486507/4687359

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For Jquery is a client-side library,I suggest that you could use LibMan.Here is the steps you could follow:

1. Create the folder `wwwroot/lib`;
2. In Solution Explorer, right-click the project folder in which the files should be added. Choose Add > Client-Side Library.
3. Search for `jquery@3.4.1` like below:

   [image]
4. Click the Install button to download the files.

Reference: [Use LibMan with ASP.NET Core in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-the-add-client-side-library-dialog)