# Razor Pages Asp.Net-Core install FullCalendar

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to install FullCalendar library to use in my Asp.Net Core Web App with Razor Pages and I installed the Nugget Package jQuery.FullCalendar.

In my Index.cshtml I use:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

And in my site.js file I use:

```
$(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    })
});
```

But when I run the app nothing happens. Did I missed some steps or this library is not working for Asp.Net Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `FullCalendar` is a client-side library,I suggest that you could use LibMan.Refer to:
[How to use LibMan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58705069/11398810).

Search for the js library:

1.moment.js:

[image]

2.FullCalendar.js:

[image]

Then your razor pages should like below:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>

@section Scripts
{
    <link href="~/lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.css" rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src="~/lib/moment.js/moment.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="~/lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({});

        })
    </script>
}
```

Be sure your _Layout.cshtml is like below:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

**Note**:If you do not apply `_Layout` to the razor pages,be sure add the `jquery.js`  firstly then add `moment.js` and `fullcalendar.js`.The order could not change.

**Another way** is that you could use cdnjs without installing the js library:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.10.2/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
```

Result:
[image]